# using ckeditor in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I need to install ckeditor in a rails project.
I need a page with the ckeditor in it, and have the option (button) to save what I did in my computer.

How can I do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked this out? https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

Comment: yes, i want to use this one, but i don't know how actually. =/

Comment: Have you tried looking through the docs on the github page? Where are you stuck?